# statfs on macOS doesn't give me full disk capacity. Why?

Tags: c++, macos, bsd

I'm trying to get the storage drive capacity and the free space on it from my macOS app.

I do the following:

```
struct statfs stStg;

if(statfs(".", &stStg) == 0)
{
    uint64_t total_sz = stStg.f_bsize * stStg.f_blocks;
    uint64_t free_sz = stStg.f_bsize * stStg.f_bfree;

    double fTotal = (double)total_sz / (1024.0 * 1024.0 * 1024.0);
    double fFree = (double)free_sz / (1024.0 * 1024.0 * 1024.0);

    printf(""%.02f GB (%.01f%% free)"
                 ,
                 fTotal,
                 100.0 * fFree / fTotal);
}
```

It gives me:

> 460.43 GB (66.5% free)

But when I check it in Finder, I'm getting a larger capacity:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1024.0 * 1024.0 * 1024.0 B is GiB, not GB. These are two different units. GB is 1000 * 1000 * 1000 B.

1024 * 1024 * 1024 / (1000 * 1000 * 1000) * 460.43 GiB = 494.38 GB

For more information, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte#Multiple-byte_units)

Comment: Interesting. You know I had exact same calculation on Windows and it counted my disk size using 1024 (that it showed in the properties for the drive C:).

Comment: @c00000fd Microsoft is very special. They don't know the difference between GiB and GB and how to implement C++.

Comment: You know I applied the same logic of using 1000 to RAM calculation on the same MacBook and got 17.2 GB instead of 16 GB. I guess Apple themselves are using two versions of this math.